# Problems with accents on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've an ASP.NET that is not displaying the accents correctly. Instead of `Direção Hidráulica\Elétrica` I'm getting:`DireÃ§Ã£o HidrÃ¡ulica\ElÃ©trica`.

I've tried unsuccessfully:

by using **HTML** on head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

By using **C#.NET**:

```
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
```

And on top of `.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page  CodePage="65001" Language="C#" ..
```

I've no idea how to fix this.

Comment: The font you are using maybe unsupported for this unicode text. do you have tried with other font where you have this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using invalid encoding.

### Convert text into html entities

You can use UTF-8 in your html by converting the characters into [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). A online converter is located here: http://konieczny.be/unicode.html

This is the resulting string (remove the spaces between the &, stackoverflow automatically converts it):

> Dire& #231;& #227;o Hidr& #225;ulica\El& #233;trica

### Save the file as UTF-8

The reason why you are getting those strange characters is because you are saving the file as ANSI. Assuming you are using Notepad, go File -> Save As. At the bottom you will find "Text Encoding". Change it to UTF-8.

This will be available in the editor that you are using. Even if you use the "charset=utf-8" in the HTML tags, it won't change how it is saved.